# How to trigger the webhook when assignee for a ticket is updated/changed

Tags: webhooks, zendesk, zendesk-api, zendesk-app, zendesk-sdk

I'm trying to call a webhook which triggers as soon as the assignee for any ticket is updated on Zendesk

Below is the condition am using currently:

[image]

But, I don't know why the webhook is not getting triggered when I change the assignee

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. Just check that your assignee really changes:
   In trigger section after action add new action: add tag "works_fine"
2. Then change assignee in ticket and check that trigger really works, if it works you see new tag in ticket
3. if trigger works you can add webhook action etc.